# how to get an alert message if the value entered is not found in the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and I'm able to loop through the array using a for loop and I can print it to the page without problems if the value is found, but I'm trying to get an alert message to display if the value is not found and continue asking for the next value until the user types quit. The problems with my code is that the alert message keeps appearing until the loops ends if the value is not found. Here's my code:

```
var message = '';
var student;
var search;

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function getStudentReport( student ) {
  var report = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
  report += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
  return report;
}

function findStudent( look ){

    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
        student = students[i];
        if (look === student.name) {
          message += getStudentReport( student );
          print(message);
        } else{
            alert(look + ' was not found');
        }

    }
    print(message);
}


while (true){
  search = prompt('Search student records: type a name [Jody] (or type "quit" to end)');
    if (search === null || search === 'quit'){
        break;
    }
  findStudent(search); 

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How does your `students` array/object look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it could be help full for you https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/YQGbar

```
    var message = '';
    var student;
    var search;
    function print(message) {
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
    }

    function getStudentReport( student ) {
      var report = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
      report += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
      report += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
      report += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
      return report;
    }

    function findStudent( look ){
    var flag=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
            student = students[i];      
            if (look === student.name) {
              message += getStudentReport( student );        
              print(message);  
              flag=0;
              break;
            } else{          
              flag=1;
            }
        }
      if(flag==1){
        alert(look + ' was not found');
        showprompt();
      }   
    }

    function showprompt(){
      search = prompt('Search student records: type a name [Jody] (or type "quit" to end)');
      if (search != null && search !== "quit"){    
          findStudent(search); 
      }
    }
    showprompt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets explain this part of code:

```
function findStudent( look ) {

    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
        student = students[i];
        if (look === student.name) {
          message += getStudentReport( student );
          print(message);
        } else{
            alert(look + ' was not found');
        }

    }
    print(message);
}
```

What that does is it loops with a for loop over an array/object and prints a message or alerts for every record inside the array. That is the problem. You only want to check if the value is found and print or alert if so.

```
function findStudent( look ) {

    var found = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
        student = students[i];
        if (look === student.name) {
            found = true;
            break;  // if the student is found no need to loop further
                    // move on with rest of code
        }
    }

    // so if the student was found in the for loop, found will be true
    // else found will be false cause we set it to false at the beginning
    if(found) {
        message += getStudentReport( student );
        print(message);
    } else {
        alert(look + ' was not found');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use indexof 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

```
else if (students.indexOf(look) == -1){
    alert(look + ' was not found');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the loop inside `findStudent()` function. 
First, add a boolean varible: `var flag = true;` 
Second, use it as condition of while loop: `while(flag){...}`
Finally, assign `flag = false`whenever want to stop the loop:

function findStudent( look ){

```
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
    student = students[i];
    if (look === student.name) {
      message += getStudentReport( student );
      print(message);
      //possible stop here if you want
      flag = false;
    } else{
        alert(look + ' was not found');
      //possible stop here if you want
      flag = false;
    }

}
print(message);
//possible stop here if you want
flag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = '';
var student;
var search;

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function getStudentReport( student ) {
  var report = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
  report += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
  return report;
}

function findStudent( look ){
    message = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
        student = students[i];
        if (look === student.name) {
            message += getStudentReport(student);
        }
    }
    return message;
}


while (true){
  search = prompt('Search student records: type a name [Jody] (or type "quit" to end)');
    if (search === null || search === 'quit'){
        break;
    }

    if(findStudent(search)){
        print(findPurpose(search));
        break;
    } else {
        alert(search + ' was not found');
    }

}
```